# Display invisible characters in Firefox

Tags: firefox, web, browser, firefox-extensions

Is there a way to visualize hidden(invisible) characters in Firefox? (or other browser) like MS Word (or other text editors) does?

Say, I want to see (count) spaces, newlines, other invisible chars... ?

If not, are there any text editors that can display these invisible characters copied from Firefox?

Comment: Might be better at superuser.com -- interesting question though.

Comment: Just curious: did you ever do a "view source"? If no: please do; do you still want to see all newlines and excessive whitespace such as indenting, which are, *by design*, ignored by a browser when rendering a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not really. You could replace them on-the-fly with printable characters, but then you won't have the original data any more.